# Error: Cannot call useFirebaseApp unless your component is within a FirebaseAppProvider

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get this error when i go createNewPost page, I do not know why, could you help me please ? What is the problem?
The other pages (homepage and profile page) does not any problem.

(I researched, but i couldn't find anything.)

**Error: Cannot call useFirebaseApp unless your component is within a FirebaseAppProvider**

my createNewPost page codes here:

```
const CreateNewPost = () => {
  const { user } = useAuth();
  const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  const postRef = useFirestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(uid)
    .collection("posts");

  const [post, setPost] = useState({
    content: "",
    imageURL: "",
  });

  const createPost = async () => {
    await postRef.add({
      content: post.content,
      imageURL: post.imageURL,
      timezone: dateFormat(),
    });
    setPost({ content: "", imageURL: "" });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-start ">
              <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
                <img
                  className="rounded-circle py-2"
                  alt="profile"
                  src={user.photoURL}
                  style={{
                    maxHeight: "80px",
                    maxWidth: "80px",
                    marginBottom: "-17px",
                  }}
                />
                <h2 style={{ marginLeft: "7px", marginTop: "16px" }}>
                  {user.displayName}
                </h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr></hr>
            <textarea
              class="form-control"
              id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
              rows="23"
              placeholder="Enter a description..."
              onChange={(e) => setPost({ content: e.target.value })}
            ></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
        <input
          class="form-control"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter the image link"
          style={{ marginTop: "7px" }}
          onChange={(e) => setPost({ imageURL: e.target.value })}
        ></input>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-end">
          <button
            type="button"
            class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"
            style={{ marginTop: "3px" }}
            onClick={createPost}
          >
            Post
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Firebase app provider in index.jsx like this, and i solved:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <FirebaseAppProvider firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}>
   <App />
   </FirebaseAppProvider>

  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```